# Android - How to put round corner on the running progress in a progress bar using custom xml drawable as background

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-drawable

I'm using a custom drawable for my progress bar:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/light_grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="15dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/indigo" />                
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and it looks like:

[image]

Now, the background appears with a round corner, but the progress (inside) is straight, and I want to make it round too, like this:

[image]

I googled but didn't find any solution.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this round corner on progress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image: you can see example of view here]

you can modify the color and size of the thumb and seekbar to do what you want.

This solution was the only way i could do this.
Hope this help

this is my seekbar :

```
         <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:background="@null"
            android:shape="oval"
            android:splitTrack="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_background"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            android:thumbOffset="10dp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/oval_seekbar_thumb" />
```

this is (progress_background.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/grey_line"
                android:startColor="@color/grey_line" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
           <shape android:shape="oval">
               <corners android:radius="5dp" />
               <gradient
                   android:angle="270"
                   android:endColor="@color/blue"
                   android:startColor="@color/blue" />
           </shape>
       </clip>
   </item>
   <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <clip>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <corners android:radius="90dp" />

               <gradient
                   android:angle="90"
                   android:endColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                   android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </shape>
       </clip>
   </item>
```

and this is the thumb (oval_seekbar_thumb.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:width="3dp"/>
            <size android:height="12dp" android:width="12dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The height of the thumb should be same as the height of the seekbar to look properly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `<clip>` tag with `<scale android:scaleWidth="100%">`. This should give the curved edges to secondary progress

Answer (score -3):

I know maybe it is obsolete question,but, just remove `<clip>` tag.